# Import Error Python 3 with tkinter classes

Tags: python, tkinter, import, python-3.7

I know this is probably quite easy to solve but I dont know the answer.

I have the following folder structure in my python3 project:

```
---UserInterface
------__init__.py
------MainApplication.py
------StartPage.py
```

(P.S. my __init__.py is empty)

Now I want to add the StartPage to my MainApplication and I try the following import.

```
from . import StartPage
```

I am getting the following error: ImportError: cannot import name 'StartPage' from '__main__'.

Can anyone tell me where the problem with importing is? (My main method is inside my MainApplication.py)

Answer (score 0):

did you just try `import StartPage`?
the error text says that there is no `StartPage` in `main`. You run `MainApplication` and it gets the name `main` after launch. This means that an attempt is being made to import `StartPage` from the `MainApplication`. But it's not there

Comment: And how can i fix it?

Comment: @slaayaah try `import StartPage` instead `from . import StartPage`